# MUI AutoComplete not picking values after filtering in first autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to retrieve data by filtering based on city and then second autocomplete should populate according to selected city it should populate related societies(municipalities) in second autocomplete. Below is my code. It is not fetching list of societies based on selected city.

```
import {React, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';


function AutocompleteDropdown() {

  const [cities, setCities] = useState([]);
  const [selectedCity, setSelectedCity] = useState(null);
  const [societies, setSocieties] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch the list of cities
    fetch('http://localhost:3031/cities')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setCities(data))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching cities:', error));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedCity) {
      // Fetch societies for the selected city
      console.log(selectedCity)
      fetch(`http://localhost:3031/cities?City=${selectedCity}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => setSocieties(data)
        )
        .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching societies:', error));
    }
  }, [selectedCity]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Autocomplete
        options={cities}
        getOptionLabel={city => city.City}
        onChange={(_, newValue) => setSelectedCity(newValue)}
        renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} label="Select a city" />}
      />
      {selectedCity && (
        <Autocomplete
          options={societies}
          getOptionLabel={society => society.City}
          renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} label="Select a society" />}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default AutocompleteDropdown;
```

Second autocomplete is not populating by taking city in first autocomplete.

Comment: Could it be a copy-paste error on this line: `getOptionLabel={society => society.City}`? i.e. should it be `society.Society` considering the other one was `city.City`?

Comment: You city is a object correct? When you select it shouldn't you select the property you want to save? `onChange={(_, newValue) => setSelectedCity(newValue?.City)}`

Comment: First Autocomplete is populated perfectly but when it comes to second one which should filter and populate with societies available in selected city in first autocomplete it doesn't show anything. All data is available in one json file object cities having name and array of societies in each city.